# Beautiful Soup parsing HTML containing JSON

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

Using Python3 and trying to parse NWS weather alerts which appear to contain JSON objects using Beautiful Soup and got this far: BS outputs this (snippet from top of output)

```
>>> soup.body
<body><p>{
    "@context": [
        "https://geojson.org/geojson-ld/geojson-context.jsonld",
        {
            "@version": "1.1",
            "wx": "https://api.weather.gov/ontology#",
            "@vocab": "https://api.weather.gov/ontology#"
        }
    ],
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/urn:oid:2.49.0.1.840.0.957a95b11de1ec54b622b137ccf43a662d44061f.001.1",
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": null,
            "properties": ....(snip)
```

From what I understand the "@context" tag indicates that the subsequent lines within braces are JSON data; is that correct?

How do I get at the elements inside the square and curly braces?

BS apparently has a JSON parser but I haven't found any good tutorials about how-to for someone who's a noob to this situation.

Pointers would be most welcome.

Comment: Are you sure the Json is inside `<p>` tag and not `<script>` tag? And no, `bs4` doesn't parse Json. For than, use `json` built-in module.

Comment: Did you review the API guidance?

Comment: As you can see there is no <script> tag in what BS returns from the URL https://api.weather.gov/alerts/active?zone=MEZ025 I'd like to work out how to get at the text within the braces, for example "id" in the snippet shown. I'll look at the json module then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question should be improved by some additional details and as mentioned in the comments it do not look like, that response is plain HTML but rather JSON.

1. HTML in your `soup` is wrapping from 'lxml' parser
2. You do not need `beautifulsoup` for that task and no it is not a JSON parser.
3. Instead use `.json()` on your response -> [docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content)

###### Example

```
...
json_data = requests.get('YOUR URL').json()

for i in json_data['features']:
    print(i['id'])

...
```